# How to change the django cms admin logo?

Tags: django, django-cms

Is there any way to change the Django CMS admin logo? I tried many things to change the logo of Django cms admin but unable to. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You could copy, modify and then include this template file in your project in the folder: `your-project/templates/cms/toolbar/items`

https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/templates/cms/toolbar/items/logo.html

You need to keep the css class `cms-toolbar-item-logo` because the JS binds to that logo and may error without it.

You can then add override the css rule for the icon by changing the content, you may need to rewrite this altogether by setting the content as empty and adding a background image:

```css
.cms-icon-logo:before {
  content:"\E02D"
}
```